BigInt error of tarsfer instruction
I'm trying to transfer custom tokens and using @solana/spl-token on JS
I've written this script:
    let toKeypair = Keypair.generate();
 
    let walPubKey = secondWallets[j].publicKey;
    let lampSupplyPerWal = supplyPerWallet * 10 ** decimals; // important line
    console.log(lampSupplyPerWal);
    transferInstriction = createTransferInstruction({  // error line
      walPubKey,
      detination: toKeypair.publicKey,
      walPubKey,
      amount: lampSupplyPerWal,
      programId: baseTokenMint
    });

And I get erorr:
...node_modules\@solana\spl-token\lib\cjs\instructions\transfer.js:33
        amount: BigInt(amount),
                ^

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined to a BigInt
    at BigInt (<anonymous>)
    at createTransferInstruction (c:\Users\nikko\PycharmProjects NewPart\solana_tz\node_modules\@solana\spl-token\lib\cjs\instructions\transfer.js:33:17)  
    at main (c:\Users\nikko\PycharmProjects NewPart\solana_tz\main.cjs:207:31)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

This is code from transfer.js (lib):
function createTransferInstruction(source, destination, owner, amount, multiSigners = [], programId = constants_js_1.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID) {
    const keys = (0, internal_js_1.addSigners)([
        { pubkey: source, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
        { pubkey: destination, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
    ], owner, multiSigners);
    console.log(amount); // I've added this line by myself
    const data = Buffer.alloc(exports.transferInstructionData.span);
    exports.transferInstructionData.encode({
        instruction: types_js_1.TokenInstruction.Transfer,
        amount: BigInt(amount),
    }, data);
    return new web3_js_1.TransactionInstruction({ keys, programId, data });
}

Log from "main.cjs" print: 6800000000000
Log from "transfer.js" print: undefined
This src code from lib docs:

How does it happens? And what can I do to fix it?
Please help, if you know :)

You'll need to wrap your transfer amount in BigInt or use BN
A few things to also correct,

The createTransferInstruction doesn't take in an object as an argument, you'll need to pass in the values to the argument.
You are transferring the token/asset to the token account and not the wallet addresses. This can be easily solved by using the `getAssociatedTokenAddressSync' method.
The programId parameter takes in the SPL Token program address you'd like to use. Current options are TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA for the OG SPL token program and TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb for the Token extensions program.
Unless you are using token extensions you can omit giving programId a value.

You should arrive at something that resembles this after the suggestions
async function transferTokens() {
    const mint = baseTokenMint;
    let toKeypair = Keypair.generate();

    let walPubKey = secondWallets[j].publicKey;
    let lampSupplyPerWal = BigInt(supplyPerWallet * 10 ** decimals); // important line
    console.log(lampSupplyPerWal);

    let transferTxIx = createTransferInstruction(
        getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(mint, walPubKey),
        getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(mint, toKeypair.publicKey),
        walPubKey,
        lampSupplyPerWal
    );

    const tx = await new Transaction().add(transferTxIx);
    //todo(OP): sign and send tx
}


Thank you, bro so much!
Your tip is so detailed, I ve do it and fix the error
But when I'm trying to stnd transaction using:
let last_signature = sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction1, [secondWallets[j]])
It is Error with: Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: invalid account data for instruction
Maybe I need to change programId, like you says to TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb
???

perhaps the mint might belong to token-22. Change to that.

No, It didn't help

Oh, sorry, my bad
Already solve this)
